# Filling a pandas dataframe with items from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am building a predictive model for fantasy football. I have scraped a website using Beautiful Soup, parsed the data into lists, created a data frame and populated the two of the columns with the appropriate lists. The parsing code looks like this:

```
stats = []
team_list = []
vs_list = []
for idx in range(len(parsed_stats)):
    try:
        stats.append(float(parsed_stats[idx][0]))
    except:
        if len(parsed_stats[idx]) > 1:
            team_list.append(parsed_stats[idx][4])
            vs_list.append(parsed_stats[idx+1][0].replace('@', ''))

qb.team, qb.vs = team_list, vs_list
```

I have 38 rows that need to be populated So now my data frame head looks like this:

```
player_id   name    team    vs  ffpts   patt    pcmp    pyds    ptds    pint    p2  ratt    ryds    rtds    r2  fum td
0   1   Matt Ryan   Atl KC  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   2   Tony Romo   Dal NYG 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   3   Robert Griffin III  Griffin,    NO  0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   4   Drew Brees  NO  Was 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
4   5   Mark Sanchez    NYJ Buf 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

The zeros need to be filled with the data in the items in the stats list. I coded this nested for loop which index correctly:

```
for idx,row in enumerate(qb.values):
    count = 4
    while count < 17:
        for val in stats:
            qb.iloc[idx,count] = val
        count +=1
```

The loop points to the right cell but fills entire data frame with zeros, not stats items. The parsed_stats list and the rest of the code is on my git hub at:
[my git hub](https://github.com/rdwyere873/draftkings/blob/master/nfl_stats_web_scrapper.ipynb)
 Any ideas?

Comment: Just giving feedback, I don't know what `parsed_stats` is.  I'd expect you to provide this so we can experiment.  I can't parse your dataframe.... this equates to me having to try to hard to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited my post to include my git hub. You can find it there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the name of your last column to `vs_2` before creating the initial data frame, since you already have a column named `vs`. After that, the following seems to work:

```
remaining_columns = columns[4:]
for num, col in enumerate(remaining_columns, start=2):
    print(num, col)
    # Flatten the list and assign it to the relevant column
    flat_list = [item for sublist in parsed_stats[num:][::19] for item in sublist]
    qb[col] = flat_list
qb.iloc[0]
```

```
player_id            1
name         Matt Ryan
team               Atl
vs                  KC
ffpts            37.00
pass_att            31
pass_comp           23
pass_yds           299
pass_tds             3
int                  0
pass2                0
rush_att             3
rush_yds            25
rush_tds             1
rush_2               0
rec                  0
rec_yds              0
rec_tds              0
rec_2                0
fum                  0
vs_2                 0
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Please double check that everything is in the right order and that the numbers make sense, I am not familiar enough with American football to assess it.